# Legacy table having problems with set_primary_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a scaffold against a legacy SQL Server database view that has a text primary key with no id column.  I have set_primary_key "Gift_ID" in the model but Im getting an error on the show method.

I can list the records okay but when I click on the show link, it errors out.  It appears to be using id to look up the record even though I have set_primary_key in the model.  Here is the complete text of the error displayed;

```
NoMethodError in PledgesController#show

undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /home/steve/RubymineProjects/otatest

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/pledges_controller.rb:16:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"PL-24681"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Can anyone shed some light on why it is still trying to use "id" as the key? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Want to post the view code that contains the "show" link as well as the controller's show method?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, so I thought I'd answer my own question in case it helps someone else;
I gave up on using the set_primary_key option in the model and added an "id" field to the view in my legacy system (SQL Server) using a key field in the data. That solved the id problem.
I also found that the generated scaffolding field names are case sensitive. So I used the view to set all field names to lowercase.  You could make sure your scaffolding case matches the legacy field names, but I found that it's easier to just set them all to lower case.
One more thing; I had a few legacy boolean fields that had a "?" on the end of the field name, the scaffolding did not like that either, so I removed the "?" in the view.

Bottom line, building a Rails app on top of a legacy system has it's challenges.  I discovered most my problems by migrating the table to the legacy database and examining the way it created the fields then modifying my view to match.